# Discount weekends and find out the number of weekdays from a date?

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to send emails only on the weekdays. The requirement is to send an escalation email to a user after number of days, with a condition to discount the Saturday & Sunday.

For example, if the first escalation was sent on 22-Oct-2013 and after 19 days if the next escalation needs to be sent, then I need to discount all the weekends and should send the email on 18-Nov-2013. (This discounts all the weekends and takes only 19 weekdays and sends the email).

Can someone share a logic as to how I can achieve this? In stack over flow, I could see posts to find the weekend between two given dates. But in my case, I need to discount the weekends and send the email only on a weekday for the give number of days.

Regards,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode (I leave it to you to translate it to C# as an exercise). It assumes that the starting date is a week day.

```
function FindTheNextWeekDayAfter (date today, int workingDays) returns date
   result = today;
   while workingDays>0
     result = result.AddDays(1)
     if result.IsWeekDay() && ! result.IsHoliday()
       workingDays--

  return result
```

This can be implemented as a DateTime extension.

Comment: It didn't work! I have the same code below in C#.. `while (selectedDays > 0)
                {
                    newDate = escalationDate.AddDays(1);
                    if (newDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday || newDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                        selectedDays++;
                }`

Comment: `if (newDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday || newDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)` - this will always be true. You probably meant to use `&&`.

Comment: As such, this logic didn't work when I debugged with && also :(

Comment: Well, first of all you should *decrease* your counter. then, you move foreward day by day and decrease your counter if the day is a working day. A working day is a day which is a week day and not a holiday. Of course this logic works, but it is *pseudocode* and you must translate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked!!

```
 private DateTime GetNextEscalationDate(DateTime lastEscalationDate, int elapsedDays)
 {
 int count = 0;
 int j = elapsedDays;

 for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
 {
     if ((lastEscalationDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ||
     (lastEscalationDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
     {
         count += 2;
         j += 2;
     }
 }
 DateTime weekendDiscountedDate = lastEscalationDate.AddDays(elapsedDays + count);
 return weekendDiscountedDate;
```

}